# How to send account recharge notifications to users, PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that it's users have an option of upgrading their accounts and get extra features. They purchase monthly packages. Like 1 month, 2 months, etc.

I want to send some notifications before their premium account expiration, I can do it with a MySQL query like

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(`end_timestamp`, NOW()) as diff
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN `start_timestamp` AND `end_timestamp` AND
DATEDIFF(`end_timestamp`, NOW()) > -1
```

this will give me list of users with active accounts, BUT my problem is that my users have an option of changing their timezone. So I have to send the notification based on their local time and BEFORE account expiration (eg. Account expires 9PM IRDT , so the last warning should be sent the same day before 9PM IRDT, its no good to send it after that time.)

I think i may have to get the list of premium users and their timezone settings every hour and calculate local time in php, but im wondering if there are better ways to do the whole process.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: or you can just send email few times... a week before, and a day before the expiration.

Comment: Yeah I think a day before is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save all timestamps into database in UTC and add an `UTC_offset` field into users table. This would allow you to make queries which take timezone into account ie using [CONVERT_TZ()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

Ie assuming that `end_timestamp` is in UTC your query would be something like

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(end_timestamp, UTC_TIMESTAMP()) as diff
  WHERE UTC_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN `start_timestamp` AND `end_timestamp` AND diff > -1
```

But if you want to show the end timestamp to the user you conwert it to his timezone:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(end_timestamp,'GMT',user.UTC_offset) as end_ts, ...
```

Comment: Can you please write me a simple query using CONVERT_TZ?

Comment: @Sallar Click on the `CONVERT_TZ` in my reply - it's a link to the mySQL help where there is also some simple examples of the use of the function.

Comment: Thanks, Im gonna try this approach.

Comment: CONVERT_TZ just saved my life. Thanks.